# Why can't I get the list of all users in a group in Django?

Tags: django, loops, templates, usergroups

This is my view.

```
def teacher_list(request):
    group = Group.objects.get(name='Teacher')
    users = group.user_set.all()
    return render(request, "acnt/teacher-list.html", { "users": users })
```

This is the template I am using.

```
{% for teacher in users %}
    <a href="#">{{ teacher.get_full_name }}</a> <br/>
    {% endfor %}

{{ users }}
```

This is the result I am getting on my template.

```
John Doe 

<QuerySet [<User: john>, <User: michel>]>
```

As you can see I have updated the group by adding another user `michel`, and the `users` object has both the users, but it is not showing in the loop I am using in the template. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try <a href="#">{{ teacher.id }}</a> <br/> instead to see if gets id

Comment: Hey thanks man. Name was not set for the second user. :)